# No resize event in content of iframe (iOS Safari)

Tags: ios, iframe, safari, resize

I have following html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var myDiv = null;

window.onload = function() {
    myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
};

function buttonClick() {
    myDiv.style.width = "200px";
    myDiv.style.height = "100px";
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" style="left:10px; top:10px; width:1000px; height:250px; overflow:auto;">
        <iframe scrolling="no" id="myIframe" style="width:100%;height:100%" src="a.svg"></iframe>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="buttonClick()" value="resize div"/>
</body>
</html>
```

and a SVG "a.svg" that is the content of the iframe above:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="500">
    <circle cx="500" cy="250" r="240"/>
    <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
window.onresize = function() {
    console.log("resize");
};
]]></script>
</svg>
```

When i now open the html page on iOS Safari and i click the button to resize the iframe to 200x100 pixels, i do not get the resize event.

But if I do the same on a PC browser like Firefox, I get the resize event.
I know that iframes are handled differently in iOS Safari, but how can I make this working ?

Comment: seems to be fixed in iOS 6 :)